# How to query list items and attachments from a list using @PnP/SP?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm using PNP SP to query list items, and their attachments. How do I write a correct and also simplified version of my current function?

The function below works, I get the results from the first query, it retrieves the ID, TITLE, LINK. But I get no results from the second query Title, Link.URL, FileName, ServerRelativeUR - however when I debug the code, I can see the second query being executed and returning the values, but the function leaves before completing the second query. How do I make this function correctly query both things and returns them to the caller?

```
private GetCompleteData() : Promise<any>
{
    let result : string = "";

    return sp.web.lists.getByTitle('LIST').items.select('Id, Title, Link').get().then( response => {
      response.forEach( item => {
        let attachments = sp.web.lists.getByTitle('LIST').items.getById(item.Id);        

        attachments.attachmentFiles.select('FileName, ServerRelativeUrl').get().then( responseAttachments => {
          responseAttachments.forEach( attachmentItem => {
            result += item.Title                       + "<br/>" +
                      item.Link.Url                    + "<br/>" + 
                      attachmentItem.FileName          + "<br/>" + 
                      attachmentItem.ServerRelativeUrl + "<br/><br/>";
          });
        });
      });

      return result;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making a REST call for each list item, you can use the `expand` property to get the data in the first REST call itself.

You can modify it from the below sample code:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("LIST").items.select("Title", "ID", "Links" "AttachmentFiles").
expand("AttachmentFiles").get().then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
});
```

You can modify it based on the requirement. This will give you will an array of list item's attachment as below:

[image]

Comment: this really worked for me! very elegant and simple! I can't express how much I'm thankful for your help! this problem was driving me crazy!

Answer (score -1):

Here is my test code which works.

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyList').items.select('Id', 'Title', 'EncodedAbsUrl').get().then( response => {
      response.forEach( item => {
        let _Item = sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MyList").items.getById(item.ID);      
        _Item.attachmentFiles.select('FileName', 'ServerRelativeUrl').get().
        then( responseAttachments => {
          responseAttachments.forEach( attachmentItem => {
            result += item.Title                       + "<br/>" +
            item.EncodedAbsUrl                    + "<br/>" + 
            attachmentItem.FileName          + "<br/>" + 
            attachmentItem.ServerRelativeUrl + "<br/><br/>";
          });
        });        
      });
    })
```

Comment: hi lee, thanks for the answer but the way you coded your solution it will not work once you put inside a function, just have a look on my my own example (our solutions are not that different) - you will get the return only from the first query but no returning values from the second query once it is placed in a private DoStuff() : Promise <any> ....